# npm publish executes but npmjs repository not receiving the update

Tags: node.js, npm

I have tried publishing the following repository 3 times and each time npm indicates that it's successful, however I can't pull the the project into other projects using `npm i superflycss/utilities-colors@3.0.5` and https://www.npmjs.com/package/@superflycss/utilities-colors is still stuck on version 2.1.6.

Any ideas what the issue could be?

Answer (score 2):

You do not have any tags in your github repo. npm has a command to update the version info. See the docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages#how-to-update-a-package

Or you can tag manually with these commands in your shell:

```
git tag 3.0.5
git push --tags
```

Comment: Is this something new and recent?  For example I'm publishing this repository the same way using the same process without issues ... https://www.npmjs.com/package/@superflycss/component-header

Comment: Tried another publish to 3.0.6 a few minutes ago.  Looks like it's just really slow at updating today.

Comment: I just read this in the docs. I do not think that this is new.